# Getting a JSONException because of a colon

Tags: java, json

I'm getting my JSON values from a linkedHashMap

```
LinkedHashMap<String,Object> lst = JsonPath.parse(json).read("$.projects[0].issuetypes[0].fields");
```

This is the JSON I'm trying to parse :

```
{
    "required": false,
    "schema": {
        "type": "string",
        "custom": "com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.customfieldtypes:textfield",
        "customId": 10161
    },
    "name": "Error Code",
    "operations": [
        "set"
    ]
}
```

Then I was thinking that this would do the job

```
 JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(lst.get(key).toString());
```

But then I got this exception:

```
   Exception in thread "main" org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONException: Expected a ',' or '}' at character 95 of {required=false, schema={type=string, custom=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.customfieldtypes:textfield, customId=10161}, name=Error Code, operations=["set"]}
```

Character 95 is the colon between customfieldtypes and textfield

What could be wrong with this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to parse a serialized object, which is not valid JSON.

```
lst.get(key).toString()
```

does not produce JSON.

Comment: The format of the error message has nothing to do with the input JSON.